# Need Help representing a workflow in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, algorithm, data-structures, graph, workflow

I need to represent the workflow of a process. I need more than a simple graph because the children of a node depend on the previous steps. Ex:

```
A  -> B -> [C, D]
A' -> B ->  C
```

Another requirement that I have is that it should be easily modified and extended, maintaining the consistency. So for example if a node doesn't exist anymore it should be able to still know the path that it took to get there and a way to continue the flow from there.

The best thing that I was able to come up is a multivalue weighted graph. The weight of an arch is determined by the version of the flow and a value inside a predetermined range (1 - 100), so if you get to the node using an arch with version 2 and value 5 you con move to adjacent nodes that have archs with version 2 and value between 1 and 100.

I know that there should be a better way to do this, but I can't come up with anything else or find anything that fits.

Comment: It would help if you explained a little more, maybe giving a concrete example. It is difficult to understand the question; much less how your proposed solution solves it.